# How to specifically obtain records between certain date values when using Query Builder in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, aspxgridview

I am trying to obtain data from a table which shows customer orders. i have opened query builder in the gridview of the data source and selected the relevant table for my query. Now i would like to display orders which are placed within the last 30 days. Which condition do i have to put into order date filter to show orders in gridview which have been placed in the last 31 days only? please someone help me and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the BETWEEN condition:

```
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

Additionally, if you have more SQL knowledge and can manually edit the query you could do:

```
WHERE OrderDate > DATEADD(DAY, -31, GETDATE())
```